# is there a function to compare values of the arrays and extract the index numbers of matches?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two arrays of strings and want to compare them by value and extract the index numbers of identical items of mainArray that are available in secondArray for example:

```js
var mainArray = ["I", "am", "not", "a", "doctor"]
var secondArray = ["am", "doctor"]

var Result = [1,4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `intersection` method of [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) library.

```js
const mainArray = ["I", "am", "not", "a", "doctor"]
const secondArray = ["am", "doctor"]

const result = _.intersection(mainArray, secondArray)
const resultIndices = result.map(i => mainArray.indexOf(i))

console.log(result)
console.log(resultIndices)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
const mainArray = ["I", "am", "not", "a", "doctor"];
const secondArray = ["am", "doctor"];
const result = secondArray.map(w => mainArray.indexOf(w));
console.log(result);
```

Note: This solution will return -1 for that cases when string doesn't match.